# MS Word (2013) How to put bullet points in a row?

Tags: microsoft-word

I want to have something like:

```
• Item1      •Item2       •Item3     • Item4      •Item5       •Item6
```

So I can just tab between items in the list with indentations and spacing being the same for all.

Comment: Several suggestions: Use tabs for the positioning and hard-code the bullet character or create a table and put each bullet in a seperate column.

Answer (score 3):

If is was me I would

- Insert a table with the same number of columns as your bullet points and only 1 row.
- Insert your items.
- Make the borders invisible